# How to close file after reading in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to close all file after reading it. Actually, i want to remove safely the SD Card, so that i need to close all file before eject but i don't know how to close file. I used the code to reading file:

```
 NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.txt", drive_url]];
    NSLog(@"url %@",url);
    NSMutableData *dataText = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }else {

        NSLog(@"Data loaded successfully");
        NSLog(@"Data %@",dataText);
    }
```

How can i close test.txt file? Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe that method reads it into RAM, and closes the file. I'm not 100% sure though...

Comment: @SimonM: my code is reading direct from sd card, not reading from cache. How can i close file?

Comment: Do you have to close it? Since you are using the `NSDataReadingUncached` option, the data is read and the operation is done. I'd be surprised if the file was kept open. Can you try and check it with the `lsof` command? I can't try it now.

Comment: @allprog: actually i want to remove safely the sd card, but when i click on eject button in Finder, it show message can not eject the card. So that, i want to close all file or dealloc data.

Comment: Try to use `lsof /Volumes/<the volume of the SD card>` to figure out what application is keeping files open.

Comment: @allprog: After check what files keep open, how to close these files ? Can you show me? Thanks so much

Comment: This command lists you all the open files with the processes that keep them open. The files are closed when those processes are killed or the belonging apps are somehow notified (using the GUI or any other app specific way). If you add the listing to the question, it will be easier to tell what you should do. For sure, don't start to `kill` processes that you are not familiar with.

Comment: @allprog: as you said, there no way to close file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38154/discussion-between-allprog-and-joson-daniel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File closes right after `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` finished. `NSDataReadingUncached` is a hint indicating the file should not be stored in the file-system caches.

Comment: Yes, if file is closed, why sd card can not remove safely ? DO you know? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately no. May the issue be somewhere else?